# Accessing shared outlook inbox from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to access shared inbox emails from Excel VBA however my code is not functioning as expected and only works on personal inbox.

I've tried the code below on a personal inbox and it works just fine. Not quite sure how to approach shared inbox, it could be the way the shared inbox is setup perhaps.

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object, MailFolder As Object, SharedMailbox as Object, OutlookItem as Object

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'This line works for personal inbox
'Set MailFolder = OutlookApp.Session.Folders("email@outlook.com").Folders("Inbox")

'Trying to modify below to access shared inbox
Set SharedMailbox = OutlookApp.Session.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com")
'This line below causes error, specifically olFolderInbox
Set MailFolder = OutlookApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(SharedMailbox, olFolderInbox) 

For Each OutlookItem In MailFolder.Items
'other code runs here
Next
```

Maybe due to my usage of late binding methods and mixing something with early binding? But I would like to keep it late binding for compatibility.

I played around with the below code but its running into similar issue.

```
Dim OutlookNS as Object

Set OutlookNS = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
OutlookNS.logon
Set SharedMailbox = OutlookNS.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com")
SharedMailbox.resolve
If SharedMailbox.resolved Then
    Set MailFolder = OutlookNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(SharedMailbox, olFolderInbox)
End If
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been sitting on this for sometime and just can't get it right. Thanks!

Comment: What does "not functioning" mean? Are you getting an exception? What it it?

Answer (score 0):

The [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method of the Namespace class returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.

I don't quite understand what you expect to get from the code, but I'd suggest adding the `Display` method show the shared folder:

```
Dim OutlookNS as Outlook.Namespace
Set OutlookNS = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
OutlookNS.Logon
Set SharedMailbox = OutlookNS.CreateRecipient("shared@email.com")
SharedMailbox.resolve
If SharedMailbox.resolved Then
    Set MailFolder = OutlookNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(SharedMailbox, olFolderInbox)
    MailFolder.Display
End If
```

Also, I'd recommend setting a breakpoint and run the code under the debugger to see what happens under the hood.